# VS 2015 Error: The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

Tags: ms-access, visual-studio-2015, odbc

I have both Access and Visual Studio applications that need to connect to a remote MySQL database.  I haven't had to work on the VS application in some time, but continuously work on and enhance the Access version. Some time ago I started having issues with my Access applications, and Microsoft tech suggested that I should NOT use the 32-Bit Office applications on my 64-Bit PC, so they talked me through uninstalling Office applications and re-installing 64-Bit Office.

Of course I had errors connecting my Access app to the MySQL database, so I downloaded and installed the 64-Bit MySQL Connector. The 32-Bit Connector was version 5.something and the 64-Bit one I was installing was 8.something, so the install did not try to delete anything. Once I renamed the old DSN and setup a new DSN (using the 64-Bit version of ODBC Data Sources) everything worked again.

Now I'm trying to use the VS application and it will not run, giving me the above error. Research shows versions of VS through 2017 are 32-Bit, so I believe the error is because the 32-Bit application is trying to use the 64-Bit version of the DSN.

So now I have 2 challenges:

1: Installing the MySQL connector causes the prior version to be deleted (since now the existing 64-Bit version and the new 32-Bit version I'm installing are both 8.something). How do I have both 32- and 64-Bit versions of the connector coexist on my PC? If I could have both installed, I could keep the 64-Bit DSN named "MySql" and add a new 32-Bit DSN called "MySql32".

2: If I can install both connectors and create different DSN's, how do I change my VS to use the proper one?  Here is a snippet of my App.Config file, which I believe is the area in question:

```
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
    <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" 
         type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

But I don't see anything in there which refers to a specific DSN.

Hope someone can help.  Thanks...

Comment: I don't understand that recommendation. 32-bit Office/Access works just fine with Windows 64-bit. In fact 64-bit Office/Access is not recommended unless certain conditions are present - review https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/choose-between-the-64-bit-or-32-bit-version-of-office-2dee7807-8f95-4d0c-b5fe-6c6f49b8d261#:~:text=You%E2%80%99re%20working%20with%20the%20Large%20Number%20data%20type,LongLong%20data%20type%20which%20fully%20supports%20large%20numbers.

Comment: I know that's true, I used 32-bit Office for years on 64-bit computers. Can't remember the problem I was having at the time, it was several months ago. In any case, that's secondary to the actual problem I'm having now. The 64-bit Office is working fine except for this new issue.

Comment: I think [this article](http://wikis.openlinksw.com/UdaWikiWeb/MsSqlOn64bitWin) will help you.  Note -- .NET Providers are not actually 32-bit or 64-bit, but the .NET Frameworks are. (Small update I'll be making to that article shortly...)

Comment: Also note that the snippet of App.Config you've provided isn't relevant, *if* you're really using ODBC, as nothing there is ODBC -- that's all .NET config info. You *can* have both 32-bit and 64-bit ODBC driver for MySQL installed on the same PC, but it can make things more complicated. Best thing to do in this case is configure identical 32-bit and 64-bit DSNs, so whichever bitness app you launch will find the right config and driver waiting.

Comment: Thanks for the article TallTed. More confused than ever. I'm connecting to a remote MySQL server, so "bitness" is unknown. I know the bitness of VS (or framework) is 32, and the MySQL connector is either 32 or 64 depending on which version I install. Problem remains that 32-bit connector works with VS & 64-bit connector works with my 64-bit Office. The MySQL installer removes already installed version when you install another version.  How can I install BOTH connectors so Office and VS can both work?

Comment: Our comments crossed in the mail. Office is using ODBC I believe, and needs the 64-bit DSN. Totally not sure about VS, it's using the .Net data provider, but with 64-bit MySQL connector installed, it doesn't work. Problem is still the connector install removes the old one, so how can I install both connectors? Once installed, maybe the .Net provider doesn't need a DSN at all? Or would I need to create both DSNs? Not sure I can do that using the same DSN name. Still first must figure out how to install 32-bit connector without having the install remove the 64-bit one, & vice-versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured this out with insight by TallTed.

Instead of installing the MySQL ODBC Connector, which I already have a 64-bit version of installed, I downloaded and installed the 32-bit .Net Connector. Then, using the 32-bit ODBC administrator I created a new 32-bit DSN with the same name as the 64-bit DSN. It seemed to allow this. Once DSN was created the .Net version works again with no changes.

Also the Access application works as well, using the 64-bit DSN.

Thanks so much for the help...